# How to pass arguments to fileURL

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I'm trying to pass arguments in NSURL of file path in the usual way:

```
(fileURL)?arg1=val1&arg2=val2
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error from the `UIWebView`:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

When I remove the arguments suffix everything works perfect. The documentation on Apple state that the method

+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path

Works like this: `"path: The path that the NSURL object will represent. path should be a valid system path..."`

Is it possible to add the arguments to fileURL? If so, how can I do it?

By the way, I succeeded to do so, if I try to load local URL file with arguments from the UIWebView with Javascript call:

```
document.location = url;
```

I try to find the solution from native code...

Comment: Can you NSLog the output from fileURLWithPath? If you're passing in the path there with arguments appended, NSURL may be escaping the `?` character to make it part of the URL.

Comment: **path**: xxxxxxx?arg1=something

**fileURLWithPath output**: xxxxxxxxxx%3Farg1=something

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I see your problem. You can't add the `?arg1=something&arg2=...` to the path, because there could be a file named like that, so NSURL escapes the `?` character to ensure it's used as a path, not part of the query string (anything after the `?` is called a query in a URL).

To do this properly, you need to set the URL by giving a properly escaped string.

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/mike/file.html"; 
NSString *query = @"option1=5&option2=hello"; // for example

NSString *encodedPath = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@?%@",
                                   encodedPath,
                                   query]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the fragment instead? It's the part of the URL after the `#` symbol. This part is never sent to the server, so shouldn't interfere with the path, but javascript on the page can still read it.

Comment: Do you mean, add # to the end of path?? if so there would be a problem because path has to be an actual file path on the file system... In any case I want to keep the convention of ?arg1=val1&arg2=val2 because I have other parts in the code which expect this kind of behavior